# Click on link based on text and href attribute protractor

Tags: selenium, protractor

This question might be easy for some people.
I want to click on a link based on href value and text in link.Below is what i am using to search for text in link.

```
var elementselected = this.coinDataTable.element(by.css('a[href*='+CoinLink+']'));
```

I tried below code but it is not working. Can someone please suggest correct usage?

```
var elementselected = this.coinDataTable.element(by.css('a[href*="'+CoinLink+'"][text='CoinText'));
```

OR

```
var elementselected = this.coinDataTable.element(by.css('a[href*='+CoinLink+']')).element(by.linkText('CoinText'));
```

or

```
var elementselected = this.coinDataTable.element(by.linkText('CoinText')).element(by.css('a[href*='+CoinLink+']'));
```

This link is inside a table. Below is HTML for whole row. There are 2 links in this row. I want to select 2nd one which has CoinText in it.

```
<tr>
<td><a href="CoinLink"><img border="0" src="../../../images/pc_cdlibrary_side_icon_img_lighterbg.gif"></a></td>
<td>1C</td>
<td>MS</td>
<td><a href="CoinLink">CoinText</a></td>
<td>$15</td>
<td>S-12 </td>
<td>B-21</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Provide `HTML` code for mentioned link

Comment: @Andersson Added HTML

Comment: @alecxe Any insights in this post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `by.cssContainingText` to find the element by text and attribute:

```
by.cssContainingText('[href*="CoinLink"]', 'CoinText')
```

Comment: Where should i specify 'a' to search this in Anchor tag?

Comment: I tried below code but it is giving me error message. CoinLink is variable i am passing from in function.
`var elementselected = this.coinDataTable.element(by.cssContainingText('[href*="'+CoinLink+'"], "CoinText"'));`
Error Message: Failed: invalid element state: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '[href*="s-12"], "CoinText"' is not a valid selector.

Comment: You can add the `<a>` tag if you want. It's not going to make a difference since the `<a>` is supposed to be the only one with an `href`.

Comment: Regarding your previous comment, your error is likely due to the quoting.

Comment: Thanks. Below code worked perfectly.
`var elementselected = this.coinDataTable.element(by.cssContainingText('[href*="'+CoinLink+'"]', 'CoinText'));`

Comment: Reason i was asking to specify anchor tag is i have another situation in my code where i need to select element with image tag src and alt tags.

Answer (score -1):

This code helps me to solve the issue

```
element(by.css('a[href*="CoinLink"]')).getText()).toContain('CoinLink')
```